# класс на Objective-C не понимает тип CGFloat

Tags: objective-c

Создаю single-view application, 
ввожу несколько строк,
Unknown type name 'CGFloat'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`?

Comment: помогло. я вообще посмотрел, CGFloat  от CoreGraphics происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Минимальный файл, который нужно заимпортить, это

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CGBase.h>
```

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` тоже работает, потому что `UIKit` в конечном итоге тоже импортит `CoreGraphics`. Но если ваш класс типа `NSObject` и вам в этом классе не нужны UI элементы, то не нужно импортить целый `UIKit` только для того, чтоб объявить переменную типа `CGFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая современный синтаксис:

```
@import UIKit;
```

Если весь UIKit не нужен:

```
@import CoreGraphics;
```